# group by dynamic interval with starting and ending point SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, window-functions

I have a table containing a column `DED` with numbers that can go from 0 to infinity. I am interested in grouping them starting always in 0 (upper bound as open and lower bound as closed interval) and get the percentage totals

Suppose I have a column with

```
DED     AMT
0.0004   4
0.0009   1
0.001    2
0.002    1
0.009    4
0.01     5
0.04     6
0.09     3
0.095    1
0.9      3
1        2
100      1
500      1
```

so I would want the following intervals:

```
DED       AMT    PAMT
0-0.01     12    0.3529
0.01-0.02  5     0.1470
0.04-0.05  6     0.1764
0.09-0.1   4     0.1176
0.9-1      3     0.0882
1          2     0.0588
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT CAST(DED/.02*.02 AS VARCHAR) +' - '+CAST(DED/.02*.02 +.01 AS VARCHAR)  AS DED, 
SUM(AMT) AS AMT,ISNULL(SUM(AMT)*1.000/NULLIF(SUM(SUM(AMT)) OVER (),0),0) AS PAMT 
FROM MYTABLE 
   WHERE DED/.02*.02<=1 
   GROUP BY DED/.02*.02
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you saying you want those specific hard coded ranges? Or is there some formula or algorithm to define the ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ROUND(DED, 2, 1)          AS DED_lower,
  ROUND(DED, 2, 1) + 0.01   AS DED_upper,
  SUM(AMT)                  AS SUM_AMT, 
  SUM(AMT) * 1.0
  /
  SUM(AMT) OVER ()          AS PAMT
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  DED <= 1
GROUP BY
  ROUND(DED, 2, 1)
```

`ROUND(DED, 2, 1)` will round Down to two decimal places.  Giving equal sized bands of 0.01 in size.

Apologies for typos or formating, I'm on my phone

Comment: thanks! I had already tried the round() thing, but I didn't include the '1' in the third parameter so it didn't work as I wanted. I looked up for it and it says it truncates the result to the number of decimals... do you know what does it exactly do?

Comment: @janf like I said, it rounds down. Any value from 0.00 to 0.00999999999999999999999999999999 get rounded down do 0.00, and then any value from 0.01 to 0.01999999999999999999999999999999 get rounded down to 0.01, and so on

Comment: Round without the third parameter rounds to the nearest value. So 0.0049 goes to 0.00 and 0.0050 goes to 0.01